# Free DashCam for iOS that supports multitasking

Tags: gratis, ios

I am looking for a free dashcam application for iOS that supports multitasking (i.e. that can record in the background so that I can display Google Maps when driving).

Comment: Is your device jailbroken?

Comment: Not jailbroken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is currently not possible on iOS without jailbreaking.
Apps are unable to take photos or video whilst the app itself is not in the foreground.

Comment: Android and iOS equivalently stupid regarding non-root restrictions…

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt I wouldn't call that stupidity. Sure, there are legitimate use cases but that would also open the doors to a lot of abuse. What if a photo app (that asks permission to access the camera, and user will give permission as it's a photo app so it makes sense) secretly starts capturing images/video in background for analytics/tracking/other privacy violation purposes ?

Comment: @André Something similar to background microphone usage could be used by iOS where the status bar is double height and red with the name of the app that is using the microphone so that the user is aware.

Comment: @grgarside well, you may not notice it if it suddenly starts while the phone is locked, and even if you're actively using the device and it starts, by the time you close the app the photo is already on some analytic server and being passed around their office if there's anything interesting on it (it takes 100ms to take a photo, upload it and violate your privacy).

Comment: There is always a trade-off between security/privacy and app features. I guess I am mostly annoyed by the fact that iPhone or Android device buyers do not have the choice to buy a rooted device, meaning that they cannot choose where in the trade-off they want to be.